# Apache Solr: Custom document router

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to implement sharding by date in my application. I know that in Solr cloud I can achieve routing to specific shard using compositeId router.

But this approach leads to pre-configured number of shards (or writing a shard splitting logic - not too hard, but cumbersome).

I was wondering if it would be possible to write a custom router as a Java class and provide it to Solr? The custom router would simple create new shard whenever the time is right (example: new month) and route new documents directly to it.

Is this possible? Or are there any resources how to achieve this? (I took a look into docs and there is not mention...)

Comment: What is your ultimate goal by doing this? Why is it important to have a new _shard_ for each date? A solution being used is to have a collection for each date, then use an collection alias to group these collections together. It'll allow you to drop collections as they age, spread each day across multiple servers with its own replication and sharding strategy (when the number of documents increase, etc.).

Comment: Our queries are usually sorted by date. And we should generally hit only one or two most recent partitions. So the goal is to be able to hint solr to search the most recent data first and not even try to go to indexes containing data older than X months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would'nt go that route. I advise you study carefully the work being done at [Time partitioned collections](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-11299). This is not complete yet, so maybe you cannot use it in the best way, but many of the building pieces are done, so you should be able to leverage most of them. Then, in the future, you could hopefully move to the full built in feature.

Comment: I will add link to official docs, in case somebody needs it: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/time-routed-aliases.html